# android maven - Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'

Tags: android, maven

I'm building an Android Project with Maven. My target is set to 21 both in AndroidManifiest and in project.properties.

When I do "mvn clean install" I get this error:

```html
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project urumobilessl: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl && /usr/local/share/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /usr/local/share/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-4.1/android.jar -M /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/res -S /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_21.0.3/res -A /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets -m -J /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/generated-sources/r --output-text-symbols /home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target --auto-add-overlay, Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

When I run the command manually, I get these errors:

```html
/home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_21.0.3/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.

/home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_21.0.3/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.

/home/juan/workspace/urumobilessl-parent/urumobilessl/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_21.0.3/res/values-v21/themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Total 117 errors of the same kind. For these resources

values-v11
values-v14
values-v17
values-v21

I'm using java version "1.8.0_20". I just created the pom, I don even have a project and Iḿ working with maven from CLI.

This is my pom.xml. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>

                <groupId>com.jp</groupId>
                <artifactId>urumobilessl-parent</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

        <groupId>com.jp</groupId>
        <artifactId>urumobilessl</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>apk</packaging>
        <name>urumobilessl - Application</name>

        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                <version>21.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
                        <version>21.0.3</version>
                        <type>apklib</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
                        <version>21.0.3</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            

             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                 </dependency>

        </dependencies>

</project>
```